# Webpack CSS Background Image Not Showing

Tags: css, webpack, background-image, webpack-dev-server

I'm having problems getting css background images showing when using webpack.

I have the following css class:

```
.fb {
  display: block;
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('../images/icons/facebook.png');
}
```

Usage (Using React so className not class):

`<div className="fb"></div>`

Below is an image of my 'web_build' folder where webpack bundles all my files into. Highlighted is the culprit image.

[image: build folder]

The following is the bundles SCSS files which I see in the Network tab of chrome dev tools. No images files show on the 'Img' tab.

```
.fb {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(1b725f86d1e04faadfad0cda2ac6ee89.png); 
}
```

All I see rendered is a 30x30px red square.

[image]

NOTES:

- If I directly reference the image using an `<img>` tag, the image shows.
- I'm using webpack-dev-server
- I'm using image-webpack-loader with the following configuration

> ```
> {
>     test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)$/i,
>     loaders: [
>         'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
>         'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
>     ]
>   },
> ```

Let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching around it turns out that including sourceMap in my CSS/SASS bundling breaks relative image URLs in CSS.

Solution: Turn sourcemaps off or specify a fully qualified publicPath URL.

The following worked for me.

```
publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080'
```

More information here
https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

The image-webpack-loader only compresses the images using imagemin.
Use [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) or [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) to load the file into your css.